# Select the updated value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on attendance base on login and logout, Is there a way I can make this code work, I'm having a problem on after successfully update the data it will go to another notepad and in there it has a select query that will display the image and basic info of user. But when I tried to logout it displays different user info and images.

Here is my code for php:

```
<?php
include_once ('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username2 = $_POST['username2'];
$password1= $_POST['password1'];
$time=date("H:i:s");
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tbl_visitor.Birthday,tbl_visitor.School_Company,tbl_visitor.Contact_number,tbl_visitor.Visitor_Address,tbl_visitor.image,tbl_visitor.Visitor_username,tbl_visitor.Visitor_id,tbl_visitor.Visitor_password,concat(Visitor_first_name,'',Visitor_last_name) as name,
    tbl_visitor_form.Time_in,tbl_visitor_form.Time_out , tbl_visitor_form.Number FROM  tbl_visitor LEFT JOIN tbl_visitor_form on tbl_visitor.Visitor_id = tbl_visitor_form.Visitor_id WHERE   tbl_visitor.Visitor_username = '$username2' and tbl_visitor.Visitor_password = '$password1' 
       order by Number DESC limit 1");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($count == 0) {
$_SESSION['error_message'] = "Incorrect username or password";
header("Location:logout.php?");

} else{
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
          $username2 = $row['Visitor_username'];
          $password1 = $row['Visitor_password'];
          $name=$row['name'];

           $id=$row['Visitor_id'];
            $image=$row['image'];




       if(empty($row['Time_in'])) {

                header("location:visitorvalidate1.php");

        } else if(empty($row['Time_out'])){  

          $InsertSql = "Update tbl_visitor_form set Time_out = '$time' where Visitor_username='$username2' and Visitor_password = '$password1' order by Number DESC limit 1 ";
          $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 
          header("location:outsuccess.php?");

        }else{
          header("location:visitorvalidate1.php");
             }
        }

    }
 }
?>
```

here is my outsuccess.php:

```
 <?php 

include_once('connection.php');

$sql = "select  Visitor_username, image, Visitor_name  from tbl_visitor_form 
order by Number DESC limit 1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

         $uname=$row['Visitor_username'];
         $name=$row['Visitor_name'];
         $image=$row['image'];

   }
?>
```

the first query above is working but the second query in select has the problem, it selects different value after the update. for example, there is two user has already login user1 and user2 when I try to logout user1 it successfully updated but it displays the info of user2 instead of user1 on outsuccess.php. Hope you can help me fix this. Advance Thanks

Comment: Why are you updating the database based on a user's password rather than their ID? That's just asking for trouble. Also, you're vulnerable to SQL injection; make use of parameterised queries to prevent this. As for your actual question, the problem is that your `outsuccess` script simply does its selection based on the most recent visitor -- make it based on the ID instead.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i tried make it a based id i tried adding where clause on outsuccess.php but got an error